# Hausdorff measure of a subset of $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to show if $d>n$ then $H^d(A)=0, A \subset R^n $ and is Borel. I have seen how it is done for an interval on $R^2$ but I am having troubles with he general case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take the set $[0;1]^n$, and cover it with dyadic cubes :

$$
[0;1]^n \subset \bigcup_{j\in[0;2^k[^n\cap\mathbf{Z}^n} \frac{j}{2^k}+[0;2^{-k}]^n
$$

For this covering you have $\displaystyle\sum_{j\in[0;2^k[^n\cap\mathbf{Z}^n} \left[\mathrm{diam}(\frac{j}{2^k}+[0;2^{-k}]^n)\right]^d=\sum_{j\in[0;2^k[^n\cap\mathbf{Z}^n}2^{-kd}$ and $[0;2^k[^n\cap\mathbf{Z}^n$ has a cardinal of $2^{kn}$ so $\displaystyle\sum_{j\in[0;2^k[^n\cap\mathbf{Z}^n} \left[\mathrm{diam}(\frac{j}{2^k}+[0;2^{-k}]^n)\right]^d=2^{kn-kd}=2^{k(n-d)}$.

Since $d$ is strictly greater than $n$ the limit of $2^{k(n-d)}$ when $k$ goes to infinity is $0$. Thus $H^d_\delta([0;1]^n)$ goes to $0$ when $\delta$ goes to zero (using the notations of the wikipage of Hausdorff measure) and so $H^d([0;1]^n)=0$. You can now use sigma (sub)additivity of $H^d$ to show that $H^d(\mathbf{R}^n)=0$, which give you easily $H^d(A)=0$.